# Symfony 2 - PHPUnit - pass $options to form test

Tags: php, forms, symfony, phpunit

i'm passing my symfony2 application to PHPUnit and i have some problems with the form test. In my form i have a `choice` list and i filled this list by passing from controller array of choices with `$options` like this :

```
//Controller
$form = $this->createForm(new AdddocType(), array(
    'docdata' => $myarray,
));

//Form
->add('myfield', 'choice', array(
    'choices' => $options['data']['docdata'],
    'multiple' => false,
    'required' => true,
    'expanded' => false,
))
```

And here my PHPUnit test :

```
public function testaddContact()
{
    $formData = array(
        'myfield' => 10,
        ...
        ...
    );

    $type = new AdddocType();
    $form = $this->factory->create($type);
    $form->submit($formData);

    $this->assertTrue($form->isSynchronized());
}
```

When i pass PHPUnit, the code stop at this line in my formType :

```
'choices' => $options['data']['docdata'],
```

My question is : How can i pass the `$options` in my PHPUnit test ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Options can be passed in the third argument of [`create()`](http://api.symfony.com/2.6/Symfony/Component/Form/FormFactory.html#method_create). It isn't very hard to find that out...